# Annotating a mapview based on type, using Parse Query

Tags: ios, parse-platform, mapkit, mkannotationview

I am developing an app that uses Parse, and I am trying to lay custom annotation images based on a location's type.

In ViewForAnnotation I have the following:

```
    CustomStoreAnnotation *ann = (CustomStoreAnnotation *)annotation;
    PFQuery* locationQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:@"tbl_location"];
    [locationQuery whereKey:@"name" equalTo:ann.title];
    [locationQuery findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *locations, NSError *error) {
        if (!error)
        {
            if ([locations count] > 0) 
            {
                //get specific pfobject and set annotation image
            }
            else
            {
                //handle empty array
            }
        }

    }];
```

This code is working, but an odd behavior occurs where the wrong image appears on the annotationView temporarily at first, but it then fixes itself. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I did not need this query at all because I could instead associate a type with each annotation when first adding them to the map. This avoids the need for the query entirely, which solved my problem.